# Subsonic Simplerepository GetPaged<T> Enum issues

Tags: subsonic3

At one point, SimpleRepository didn't support enums. If you had a POCO object with an Enum it wouldn't persist correctly, you had to have a backing variable which you would use eg:

```
public enum Color
    {
        Red = 1,
        Blue = 2
    }

    public class Car
    {
        [SubSonicIgnore]
        public Color CarColor
        {
            get
            {
                return (Color)ColorMe;
            }
            set
            {
                ColorMe= (int)value;
            }
        }
        public int ColorMe;
    }
```

The name in your table would then have to be the named of the variable, and not the enum.

**This issue was resolved with a recent patch on github.**

However, I'm still seeing issues when trying to use GetPaged

```
var results = Db.GetPaged<Car>(1, 10);
```

Throws an exception:

```
**Tests.Models.NewTests.SimplePagedSearch threw exception:  System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'Models.Car.Color**
```

This exception occurs at line 95 of

SubSonic.Extensions.Objects.ChangeTypeTo(Object value, Type conversionType) in C:\TEMP\subsonic\SubSonic.Core\Extensions\Objects.cs: line 95

Answer (score 0):

I patched Subsonic.Extensions.Objects.ChangeTypeTo line 95 to include this clause:

```
  else if (conversionType.IsEnum)
        {
            return Enum.ToObject(conversionType, value);                
        }
```

So a direct cast from int32 to Enum no longer throws and exception